# How to initialize a two dimensional array of UIButtons in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array, uibutton

I'm trying to convert a one dimensional array of UIButtons into a two dimensional array of them. In order to do this, I need to instantiate an empty two-dimensional array of UIButtons with nil values that I could then point to the respective UIButton in the one-dimensional UIButton array. I'm getting confused by Optionals since I'm new to Swift. Here's my one-dimensional array:

```
@IBOutlet var noteUIButtonArray: [UIButton]?
```

And I would like to convert this 128-size one-D array into a two-D [8][16] array of UIButtons with will values. How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have 128 buttons?  I feel like if you take a step back and explain what you're doing we can probably suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an array value can be `nil`, then the type it is holding must be an *optional* type.  You need a two-dimensional array of `UIButton?` which is just an array of array of `UIButton?` or `[[UIButton?]]`.

Arrays have a handy initializer that takes the count of the items and the value you want to initialize with and creates the array.  In your case, with a two-dimensional array, you will need to use this initializer twice: once for each row of the array and once for each column.

The inner initializer will create an array of `16` `nil` values:

```
let row:[UIButton?] = Array(count: 16, repeatedValue: nil)
```

The outer initializer will create an array of `8` rows:

```
var buttons2D:[[UIButton?]] = Array(count: 8, repeatedValue: row)
```

You typically nest both of these together to initialize a two-dimensional array like so:

```
var buttons2D:[[UIButton?]] = Array(count: 8, repeatedValue: Array(count: 16, repeatedValue: nil))
```

Note that the original array is an *optional* array of `UIButton` or `[UIButton]?`.  This means that the array might not exist at all (it can be `nil`), or if it does exist it holds items of type `UIButton`.  This array cannot hold `nil` values.  When accessing a value in this array, you have to unwrap the array value.  A safe way to do that is to use *optional chaining*.

For example, to access the first button in `noteUIButtonArray`, you'd write:

```
let button = noteUIButtonArray?[0]
```

The `?` *unwraps* the *optional* array and allows you to access item `0`.  If `noteUIButtonArray` is `nil`, then the *optional chain* will be `nil`, so `button` will receive the value `nil`.  Since `button` can receive `nil`, its type is `UIButton?`.  So, even though the array can't hold optional values, you will receive an optional value from the *optional chain* which then will need to be unwrapped to use it.

Then you could loop through your array of `128` buttons an assign them to your 2D array:

```
if noteUIButtonArray?.count >= 128 {
    var i = 0

    for row in 0..<8 {
        for col in 0..<16 {
            buttons2D[row][col] = noteUIButtonArray?[i++]
        }
    }
}
else {
    print("Warning: there aren't 128 buttons")
}
```

You might want to assign your buttons in a different order.  This is just an example of one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you!! I was really close on the syntax it turns out, I was just using [UIButton] where I should have had Array in the initialization.